# How do i check if my file was uploaded and then echo my file uploaded statement to paticular part of my website

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have two php document. `form.php` and `upload.php`. Form.php displays my upload file button and it is visible to the enduser. `upload.php` carries out the action and it is not visible to the user but has the `include("form.php");` statement so anything i echo on this page goes back to my form.php page to be displayed.

first i want to know how i check my upload code with an if statement to see if the file was correctly uploaded to the server. my upload code is

**code**

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");.
```

secondly if the upload was successful i want the if statement to echo "the file was uploaded" or else echo "the file was not uploaded."

finally since the echoes are echoed back to my form.php i want to know how to echo the message in a specific div in my `form.php`. Rather than it echoing at the bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`move_uploaded_file` returns true on success. In **upload.php**;

```
    <?php
    ....
    $res = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");
$_SESSION["res"]=true;

    if ($res) {
        header("Location:form.php?res=success");
    } else {
        header("Location:form.php?res=error");
    }
```

And in **form.php**;

```
<?php
.....

$res = $_GET["res"];

......
?>
<div>
<?php if ($res == "success" && !empty($_SESSION["res"])) {
    echo "File uploaded";
} else {
    echo "Error occured";
}
unset($_SESSION["res"]);
?>
</div>

.....
```

Comment: thanks worked perfect although when my form page first loads up before i even do anything it says error occured

Comment: @user257033 I have put session control, you can see my updated asnwer

Answer (score 0):

In **upload.php**, use this:

```
<?php
....
try
{
 $res = move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],"./medetrax_backup/{$_FILES['file']['name']}");
}
catch(Exception $e)
{
 echo "An exception occurred while uploading the file. Process will quit now";
 die;
}

if (isset($res)) 
{
    header("Location:form.php?res=success");
} 
else 
{
    header("Location:form.php?res=error");
}
?>
```

And in **form.php**, check using this:

```
<?php
.....
$res = isset($_GET["res"])?$_GET["res"]:false;

......
?>
<div>
<?php if ($res) 
{
if($res=="success")
        echo "File uploaded";
else
        echo "Failed to upload file";
} 
else 
{
//draw your upload button here, in same file.
}
?>
</div>

.....
```